# SAS date macro and compress function

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am struggling with this compress function in the code below that I am trying to convert.

Old code: (This code works and returns the results below)

```
data _null_;
%let startdt='2015/11/1'; 
date_num=compress(&startdt,"'");
call symputx('date_num',date_num);
%put &startdt;
%put &date_num;
run;
```

This code returns values for the macro variable startdt as 2015/11/1 and datenum as 2015/11/1.

I am trying to achieve similar functionality using macro variables for dates.

New code: (This code gives me an error and I am not able to figure out why)

```
data _null_;
dt = date();
last_mth_beg = intnx('month',dt,-1,'beginning');
call symput('startdt',put(last_mth_beg,YYMMDDS10.));
date_num=compress(&startdt,"'");
call symputx('date_num',date_num);
%put &startdt;
%put &date_num;
run;
```

I am getting an error when I run this new code. I would like to get results as in the old code. 
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Move your `%LET` and `%PUT` statements to either before or after your data step, since that is when  SAS is going to evaluate them it makes your code easier to read and understand.  Leaving them in the middle of the data step makes it look like they are some how being evaluated while the data step is running, which is not true.  Does that fix your issue?

Comment: Hi, That does not resolve the issue. The error is in the 'New code' that does not have the let statement. Thanks!

Comment: Your second data step should also run fine, but you do need to move the `%PUT` statements to after the `run;` statement. Otherwise they will generate an error that the macro variables don't exist or, perhaps worse, show you the values they had BEFORE the data step ran.

Answer (score 0):

Your first data step is just removing the quotes from your macro variable. You can do this in macro code by either using `%sysfunc()` to call the `compress()` function. Or even just use the `%scan()` function.

```
%let date_num = %scan(&startdt,1,%str(%'));
```

In the second one it looks like you are trying to use INTNX() function on the date value. But your macro variables do not contain date values. If you want to treat '2015/11/1' as if it was a date then you will need to use an input function to convert it first.

```
%let last_mth_beg = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&date_num,yymmdd10)),-1,b),yymmdd10);
```

Comment: I added the old code for reference only, as that is the result I am trying to achieve by avoiding the hard coding of dates. I tried using the statement above, however I am getting a missing value now. Thanks!

Comment: Code works fine. It is assuming that your macro variable STARTDT has a vaid date in YYYY/MM/DD format with single quotes around it. It will generate the new macro variable LAST_MTH_BEG in YYYY/MM/DD format, but without the single quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your old code is not giving you an error. The first time you run it, you should see the error,

> WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference DATE_NUM not resolved.

Then, after the data step has run, `&DATE_NUM` will have a value. You cannot use `%PUT` inside a data step to display a macro variable you are creating within the data step.

In your second set of code, the value of the `STARTDT` macro variable you are creating does not have single quotes around it in the first place. If you just run the following, you will get the correct result:

```
data _null_;
dt = date();
last_mth_beg = intnx('month',dt,-1,'beginning');
call symput('startdt',put(last_mth_beg,YYMMDDS10.));
run;

%put &startdt;
```

When I run it, I see

> 2016/11/01